# regular expression does not fail when it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regular expression as such:

```
var pat = new RegExp("[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}");
```

I use jQuery to get a number from a textbox as such:

```
var theValue = $(item).val();
```

I've been entering numbers and testing the regex with this line:

```
alert(pat.test(theValue));
```

If I enter the number .111 it passes. This should not be the case as the first digit has to be 0-9 followed by a period and then followed by another digit 0-9. I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why bother adding the `{}` parts?

Comment: can you reproduce in a fiddle?

Comment: @ianpgall: the {n} notation ensures that the previous expression is matched at least n times. [0-9]{1} gives him his validation that a number occurs once before the decimal and once after the decimal.

Comment: @Sheridanbulger I know what it does, but I guess I'm used to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-plus

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZyzK/)

Comment: @ianpgall On second though yeah.. if he wants to just match one digit, he should just use [0-9], since it's not lazy.. I mixed up what was the desired effect sorry.

Comment: @Sheridanbulger I'm not even sure what they want anymore. I think using `{1}` means at least one match (with no upper bound), which is the same as `+`. But I'm not sure if that's true - in the docs, it says it's `Equivalent to {1,}` - note the ",".

Comment: @ianpgall I mixed my metaphors at first. {n} is exactly n times, {n,} is at least n times, both can also be lazy. So [0-9]{1} === [0-9]. He could also possibly use \d which matches digits, depending on what he wants.

Comment: @Sheridanbulger And there you go. Haha that saved me time from testing whether the "," meant something. So yeah, that's good to know, and you have already updated that in your answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use in a string, you need to escape the `\` in order for the backslash character to appear.

```
var pat = new RegExp("[0-9]{1}\\.[0-9]{1}");
```

A more concise, and perhaps more reliable form would be this:

```
/[0-9]\.[0-9]/
```

Assuming the pattern should match a single number followed by a period followed by another single number.

Comment: +1 for spotting this first, but it's worth pointing out that `{1}` is _never_ required, and the regex literal (e.g. `/\d\.\d/`) would be better than the RegExp constructor for a static regex.  If only on style grounds.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: Agreed on both points. `/[0-9]\.[0-9]/` would be better style. Or `/\d\.\d/` though I've got to admit that I don't remember if `\d` will match more than just `0-9`.

Comment: thank you for this, it's always something simple. good point on the style and {1}.

Answer (score 5):

Your backslash is doing a string escape rather than a regular expression escape. Either use:

```
new RegExp("[0-9]{1}\\.[0-9]{1}");
```

or the preferred-by-many forward slash ([RegExp literal](http://es5.github.com/x7.html#x7.8.5)) syntax:

```
/[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}/
```

**Edit**: Also, as ianpgall points out above, the {1} is not necessary because the character class `[0-9]` is not lazy unless followed by a `?`.

Comment: re "...[0-9] is not lazy unless..."; Laziness has nothing to do with it.  Like any other regex atom, the character class matches exactly once unless you specify otherwise by tacking a quantifier onto it.  So the pseudo-quantifier `{1}` telling the regex engine to do what it was going to do anyway.

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. That's exactly what I said in different words. I was trying to show the OP why the {1} is not necessary for what he wants to do. Since he put the {1} in the expression in the first place, I'd assume he would have thought it was lazy, otherwise why bother. Clearly he thought he needed it for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine if you instead of quotes, you write the regex with slashes

```
var pat = /[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}/;
var theValue = ".111";
alert(pat.test(theValue));
​
```

And I'd use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Your `\.` in the string was escaping the `.` in the string, not in the regex.  So your regex was effectively `[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}` which matches a digit, anything, and then another digit. instead of digit, period, digit.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to anchor the expression.

```
var pat = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}$");
```

Comment: That's not the reason why it passes.

Comment: @acheong87: Even without the anchors, 111 should still not pass, hence, the downvote.

Comment: Agh I disagree, the question says "the first digit has to be 0-9 followed by a period and then followed by another digit 0-9" so anchoring _is_ also an important factor with respect to meeting the desired result.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - I'm sorry; for some reason in my mind, I read that a decimal number like 1.11 was passing; undone. Apologies, again.

Comment: The fact is that both the anchor and the `\\` is required to fix it. It doesn't make sense that "aaa111.1" should pass, which it would in the other answer.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: The first digit isn't necessarily the first character.

Comment: @ianpgall: That's true, which is why I removed my downvote (someone else downvoted it at the same time).

Comment: I just wanted to lay out BOTH things that were wrong. At the same time, @blackcatweb hasn't fixed their answer to double escape, so it isn't correct. But the other answer hasn't included the anchor, so it isn't correct either. Haha

Comment: @ianpgall: How do you know an anchor is needed?

Comment: @user1689607 "I use jQuery to get a number from a textbox as such" and "I've been entering numbers and testing the regex with this line:"...which to me, means that should be the only thing in the textbox. But it's definitely up to what the OP wants.

Comment: @ianpgall: Fair points. I'm not really sure if OP is going to use it to capture the valid part, or to use it for validation in order to give feedback to the user. For a more strict validation, it would seem that it should be anchored.

Comment: @user1689607: Oh of course, but it's still probably what the user meant.  It _is_ good practice to anchor regex when validating form fields (if that is the use case here, I can only assume so without further information) so there's nothing wrong with suggesting it because it is sometimes overlooked by novices.  So it's a little cruel to downvote good advice, in my opinion (see http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: You seem to be implying that I down-voted this answer. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @user1689607: No I should have perhaps put my last sentence in a separate comment.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: Rock on! I'll give this a +1 anyway since I agree that the quantity of DVs seems a little excessive. The anchoring is certainly a valid possibility and it does work as expected for the only actual test that was case provided.

Comment: The extra backslashing comment was also relevant.  Anchoring would have been an issue if the user was looking only for <digit>.<digit> as valid responses.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the best answers, I thought of enhancing bit more so that this can handle most of the cases.

```
var pat = new RegExp("[0-9]{1}\\.[0-9]{1}");
var theValue = $("#item").val();
if (theValue.length == 3)
    alert(pat.test(theValue));
else
    alert("false");
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/Bv2xM/)**

Comment: Why bother checking the length, when the regex already does that and it's already been declared? Also, depending on what the OP actually wants, they may or may not want a number only, or in the middle of a string, which this wouldn't help.

Comment: I agree, why bother consolidating the answers for this question (especially so badly).  The regex as it stands does not check the length, but it could. e.g. `/^\d\.\d$/` enforces the length (so this answer is not great).  The regex in this answer would match "12.3" or "£10.52" or "-1.0".

Comment: @ianpgall: Actually it looks like that but it fails on `1.11`. Similar representations

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: My code won't match with these "12.3" or "£10.52" or "-1.0". Please look at the fidder.

Comment: @SivaCharan: I'm just talking about the regex, not the whole code - but you don't need the rest of the code if your regex was better.

Comment: Thats the reason, posted another answer

Comment: The question is a regex question.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: Yes you are absolutely correct. If the regex is `/^\d\.\d$/` then its the best.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: It would be better, if you post the mentioned regex as your answer.

Comment: Yeah maybe.  But the answers already given sufficiently explain _why_ the attempted regex did not work as expected.  There's no real need to add yet another answer, just to demonstrate that the regex could be perfected, sometimes even the best advice can be an unwanted distraction (http://www.etre.com/blog/2007/09/wiios_laws_communication_usually_fails/).